# Web driver trying to download version, but failing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My code was working normally. However since today I started having this problem

> Exception has occurred: Exception
> No such driver version 122.0.6261.112 for win32

I have tried to use this code, because once I had this error.

```
import pyautogui as pa
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

op = Options()

driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=op)
```

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format your question, especially the code and the error message so that they are readable.

Comment: My guess is that you need to update Selenium to newest. Chromedriver moved the location of the driver downloads a few months back and it required an update for driver managers. As of Selenium 4.6+, you no longer need external driver managers because Selenium Manager takes care of that now. So remove your current driver manager, update Selenium to newest, and try the script again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
pip install --upgrade webdriver_manager
```

Once I got the same problem and upgrading the webdriver was the solution.

Comment: My friend I had not tried it yet, but I tried and yes solved! thanks ma friend!

Answer (score 0):

> As of version 4.6.0, all releases of Selenium (Java, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, and .Net) are shipped with Selenium Manager.
> https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/

No need webdriver manager any more.

Update selenium and try this.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
```